# keyerror in python lambda - alexa skill

Tags: python, python-3.x

Building my first AlexaSkill and trying to use https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-build-a-custom-amazon-alexa-skill-step-by-step-my-favorite-chess-player-dcc0edae53fb. Instead of the chess script I have changed it a little to give an insult about how someone smells rather than a player bio.

When executing if the playername doesnt match then the code flows correctly, however when the player name does match someone I have in the code I get a keyerror.

error detail

> 2021-01-24T14:53:02.721+00:00
>
> Copy 'daddy': KeyError Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 24, in lambda_handler
> return intent_scheme(event)   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 53, in intent_scheme
> return player_bio(event)   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 69, in player_bio
> return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()],
> card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False) KeyError: 'daddy'

executing code

```
#------------------------------Part1--------------------------------
# In this part we define a list that contains the player names, and 
# a dictionary with player biographies
Player_LIST = ["John", "Horatio", "Daddy", "Mummy"]

Player_BIOGRAPHY = {"John":"peeee-you, Jasper smells like a stinky pair of week old socks that have been left out in the rain",

"Horatio":"Ughhhh, Horatio smells just like an elephant's bum that has been sweltering in the desert for a month",

"Mummy":"Mummy smells beautiful, like the scent of freshly cut roses or sweet perfume",

"Daddy":"Oh wow, the worst. He smells like a combination of burnt popcorn and rotting fish combined with sewer water and stinky armpits"}
#------------------------------Part2--------------------------------
# Here we define our Lambda function and configure what it does when 
# an event with a Launch, Intent and Session End Requests are sent. # The Lambda function responses to an event carrying a particular 
# Request are handled by functions such as on_launch(event) and 
# intent_scheme(event).
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['session']['new']:
        on_start()
    if event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "IntentRequest":
        return intent_scheme(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_end()
#------------------------------Part3--------------------------------
# Here we define the Request handler functions
def on_start():
    print("Session Started.")

def on_launch(event):
    onlunch_MSG = "Hi, welcome to the Stinkbot Alexa Skill. My favourite players are: " + ', '.join(map(str, Player_LIST)) + ". "\
    "If you would like to hear more about a particular player, you could say for example: Does daddy smell?"
    reprompt_MSG = "Do you want to hear more about a particular player?"
    card_TEXT = "Pick a player."
    card_TITLE = "Choose player."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(onlunch_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def on_end():
    print("Session Ended.")
#-----------------------------Part3.1-------------------------------
# The intent_scheme(event) function handles the Intent Request. 
# Since we have a few different intents in our skill, we need to 
# configure what this function will do upon receiving a particular 
# intent. This can be done by introducing the functions which handle 
# each of the intents.
def intent_scheme(event):
    
    intent_name = event['request']['intent']['name']

    if intent_name == "playerBio":
        return player_bio(event)        
    elif intent_name in ["AMAZON.NoIntent", "AMAZON.StopIntent", "AMAZON.CancelIntent"]:
        return stop_the_skill(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return assistance(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.FallbackIntent":
        return fallback_call(event)
#---------------------------Part3.1.1-------------------------------
# Here we define the intent handler functions
def player_bio(event):
    name=event['request']['intent']['slots']['player']['value']
    player_list_lower=[w.lower() for w in Player_LIST]
    if name.lower() in player_list_lower:
        reprompt_MSG = "Do you want to hear more about a particular player?"
        card_TEXT = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        card_TITLE = "You've picked " + name.lower()
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()], card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
    else:
        wrongname_MSG = "You haven't used the full name of a player. If you have forgotten which players you can pick say Help."
        reprompt_MSG = "Do you want to hear more about a particular player?"
        card_TEXT = "Use the full name."
        card_TITLE = "Wrong name."
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(wrongname_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
        
def stop_the_skill(event):
    stop_MSG = "Thank you. Bye!"
    reprompt_MSG = ""
    card_TEXT = "Bye."
    card_TITLE = "Bye Bye."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(stop_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)
    
def assistance(event):
    assistance_MSG = "You can choose among these players: " + ', '.join(map(str, Player_LIST)) + ". Be sure to use the full name when asking about the player."
    reprompt_MSG = "Do you want to hear more about a particular player?"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked for help."
    card_TITLE = "Help"
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(assistance_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def fallback_call(event):
    fallback_MSG = "I can't help you with that, try rephrasing the question or ask for help by saying HELP."
    reprompt_MSG = "Do you want to hear more about a particular player?"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked a wrong question."
    card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(fallback_MSG, card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
#------------------------------Part4--------------------------------
# The response of our Lambda function should be in a json format. 
# That is why in this part of the code we define the functions which 
# will build the response in the requested format. These functions
# are used by both the intent handlers and the request handlers to 
# build the output.
def plain_text_builder(text_body):
    text_dict = {}
    text_dict['type'] = 'PlainText'
    text_dict['text'] = text_body
    return text_dict

def reprompt_builder(repr_text):
    reprompt_dict = {}
    reprompt_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(repr_text)
    return reprompt_dict
    
def card_builder(c_text, c_title):
    card_dict = {}
    card_dict['type'] = "Simple"
    card_dict['title'] = c_title
    card_dict['content'] = c_text
    return card_dict    

def response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    speech_dict = {}
    speech_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(outputSpeach_text)
    speech_dict['card'] = card_builder(card_text, card_title)
    speech_dict['reprompt'] = reprompt_builder(reprompt_text)
    speech_dict['shouldEndSession'] = value
    return speech_dict

def output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    response_dict = {}
    response_dict['version'] = '1.0'
    response_dict['response'] = response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value)
    return response_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

In *player_bio* function you return `return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(Player_BIOGRAPHY[name.lower()], card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)`. You are using `name.lower()` (i.e. lowercase string) to get items from *Player_BIOGRAPHY* dictionary, but the keys in that dictionary are title cased. Replace `name.lower()` with `name.title()`

Comment: is it the same outocme if I change the keys in the dictionary for lower case keys?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be the same outcome. Just make sure to match the format of the keys in the dictionary and how you're trying to access those values (if it's uppercase in dict, use uppercase to access the values, if it's lowercase, use lowercase, etc.)